# PHP load data in modal

Tags: php, mysql, modal-dialog

I need to load data from a database table using an ID that is sent to a modal window.

Basically, when the grid loads, there are multiple columns. Two in particular are called CONTAINER_ID and WORKFLOW.

Whatever is returned for WORKFLOW will be a link that opens up a MODAL popup called #mySVCModal.  Here is the sample code:

```
 while(($Row = mysql_fetch_assoc($QueryResult)) !== FALSE)
 {
   echo "<tr";
   echo "<td style=\"width: 50px;\">{$Row[CONTAINER_ID]}</td>";
   echo "<td style=\"width: 50px;\"><a class=\"open-container\" 
             data-toggle=\"modal\" href="#mySVCModal\" 
             data-cont=\"{$Row[CONTAINER_ID]}\">{$Row[WORKFLOW]}</a></td>";
   echo "</tr>";
 }
```

When the user clicks on {$Row[WORKFLOW]}, a modal window opens up with the CONTAINER_ID from the same row.

Here is the javascript that makes that happen:

```
 echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">
          $(document).on(\"click\", \".open-Container\", function() {
          var myContainer = $(this).data('cont');
          $(\".modal-body #containerID\").val( myContainer );
          });
       </script>";
```

At this point, the modal window is open, and I can display the CONTAINER_ID. Here is the code that displays the CONTAINER_ID:

```
 <div id="mySVCModal">
   <form action="" method="POST">
     <input type="text" name="containerID" id="containerID" class="containerID" />
   *** more code here ***
   </form>
 </div>
```

So no problem. The CONTAINER_ID is displayed in an INPUT field called "containerID".

What I need to make happen now is when the modal window opens, "containerID" is sent to a PHP variable that will retrieve the WORKFLOW information from a database table called WORKFLOW_TABLE.

When I try to convert containerID into a PHP variable and echo it out, nothing is displayed:

```
 <?php
 $containerID = $_POST['containerID'];
 echo "this is containerID " . $containerID;  // only displays the text, not the $containerID
 ?>
```

I know that once I can get the code directly above to display the containerID in an ECHO, I can run a query off of it.

So basically, what I need to do is when the modal window opens, PHP will take containerID and run a " SELECT * FROM WORKFLOW_TABLE where CONTAINER_ID = 'containerID' ";

The contents from WORKFLOW_TABLE should automatically be displayed in various INPUT fields. I'm just using INPUT fields for now. That's beside the point.

So all in all, I need the modal to open up with the contents from WORKFLOW_TABLE displayed using the containerID.

I hope I worded this clearly.

Please help.

Comment: You are missing a `>` here: `echo "<tr";`. You should also try a coding style guide and [improve the code and HTML](http://www.phtml.org). Void tags are only ending with `/ >` in XHTML, not in  HTML4 and HTML5. I think you are also missing `.modal-` classes on the modal container.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need an AJAX query.

```
<script>
function loadData()
{
  var xmlhttp;
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
  else
  {
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
  {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
    {
      document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
  xmlhttp.open("GET", "db_query.php?containerID = " + document.getElementById('containerID').getAttribute('value'), true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}
window.onload = loadData;
</script>

<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

Sorry in advance for any possible flaws, I didn't actually run this.

Comment: OP is using jQuery, why not simply use `$.get()`?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're not actually submitting your form to the server when you're loading the modal.

Since you probably don't want to reload the entire page to display the modal, you should request the modal content on demand using an asynchronous request.  Since your sample code uses jQuery, I've used the same here.  ([see the jQuery.load() documentation for more info](http://api.jquery.com/load/))

```
echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">
          $(document).on(\"click\", \".open-Container\", function() {
              var myContainer = $(this).data('cont');
              $(\".modal-body #containerID\").val( myContainer );
              $('.modal-body').load(
                  'yourPHPscript.php', 
                  { containerID: $('#containerID').val()}
              );
          });
       </script>";
```

Then your PHP script should resemble this (notice the change from POST to GET):

```
<?php
 $containerID = $_GET['containerID'];
 echo "this is containerID " . $containerID;
 ?>
```